# Launching an external activity from Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I got this this code to launch Googles Car Home:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("com.android.carhome", "CarHome");
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
```

However, I got following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6604): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.carhome/com.android.carhome.CarHome}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml
```

How do I declare this in the anifest? I googled quite a lot, but didn't find the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you declare Receiver in your manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name=".CarHome" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.android.carhome.CarHome"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

However, I'm not sure if you can start external intent as receiver. You must start it as separate activity with DEFAULT category and all that stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error. I also tried replacing <receiver> with <activity>, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can run external Activity as Reciever.